# Javascript TypeError with JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following club.json data:
`

```
{
  "cId-0-001": {
    "profile": {
      "name": "Cousin's Bookclub",
      "image": "/public/images/clubs/cId0-001-main.jpeg"
    },
    "members": ["uId-0-001", "uId-0-002"]
  }
}
```

`

```
import * as clubDatabase from "../../database/clubs.json";
JSON.parse(clubDatabase)
```

in my app, I want to convert back to a javascript object with JSON.parse(), but I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value.

What am I doing wrong?

I validated my json, but I still cannot figure out my issue.

Comment: `clubDatabase` probably already is an object

Comment: club.json is already Object, no need to parse

Answer (score 0):

You are importing json contents as a module instead of JSON object.

```
import clubDatabase from "../../database/clubs.json";
```

The above import will assign json file's contents to clubDatabase.